# How does ADB in Android talks to device over USB?

Tags: android, usb, adb

If I disable access to USB devices through USB MSC, or UMS, MTP, and PPT. Would I still be able to debug  and deploy applications to Android devices using ADB?

I might have to close UMS,PPT, and MTP due to security reasons.

Does anybody know how Android ADB works over USB? What protocol does it use? Does the device need to be mounted?

Answer (score 0):

Neither of UMS/PTP/MTP is required for `adb` to work. `adb` binary handles the [protocol](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/protocol.txt) all by itself.